# Lazy evaluation of default parameter in clojure

Tags: function, clojure, lazy-evaluation, destructuring

I have created a function with an optional argument a with a default value corresponding to the result of a function call :

```
(defn mycall[]
  (print "*** called")
  100)

(defn hello [& {:keys [a] :or {a (mycall)}}]
              (print a))
```

Upon running my function, I find that the function call for default is evaluated EVEN if I provide a value for the argument 'a'

```
(hello :a 22)
*** called
22
```

Why does this happen? I would have expected not printout '*** called' and is there a way to not have the default function evaluation if I supply the named parameter?

Does anyone have any suggestion to implement this differently ?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this happen?

During destructuring, `{:keys [a] :or {a (mycall)}}` becomes something like

```clj
(let [a (get the-map-arg :a (mycall))]
  ...)
```

It uses the arity of `get` that accepts a default value. Since `get` is a plain function, its arguments always have to be evaluated before the function itself is called.

> is there a way to not have the default function evaluation if I supply the named parameter?

Yes, albeit it's not that straightforward if you want for the default value to be evaluated only once:

```clj
(defn mycall[]
  (print "*** called")
  100)

(let [default-a' (delay (mycall))]
  (defn hello [& {:keys [a] :or {a ::default}}]
    (let [a (if (= a ::default)
              @default-a'
              a)]
      ...)))
```

If you don't care how many times the default value is evaluated or if you need to have it evaluated whenever `:a` is missing, simply remove the delay altogether and put `(mycall)` where `@default-a'` is.

Comment: Thanks I didn't quite follow that second part where I need it evaluated ONLY if :a is missing.

Comment: @dedupe Assuming you mean the code block above and not the note underneath it, if `:a` is present then its value will be used, but if it's missing, the `::default` value will be used that will be replaced with a value of the delay that wraps a call to `mycall`. I'm not sure what else I can add.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Maybe this whole approach to defaults via functions is not great

Comment: In general, the ideal approach in Clojure is to write pure functions (which have no side effects), so it does not matter whether nor how often they are called.

Comment: @JamesElliott Even pure functions can be expensive to compute.

Comment: Yes, which is why pragmatism sometimes outweighs ideal. But don’t optimize until you have evidence you need to.

Comment: @amalloy As regard pure functions being expensive to compute, causing inexplicit side-affects as described in the question is something you should avoid like fire